# Swift, can an array literal containing integers be used interchangeably with an array of integers?

Tags: swift

In my example I have a method accepting an IndexSet:

```
func printIndexSet(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
    indexSet.forEach {
        print($0)
    }
}
```

If I try to pass it an array literal containing integers, it can deduce its type and construct an indexSet:

```
printIndexSet([1, 2]) // Compiles fine
```

If I give it an array of integers though it will not compile

```
// The following fail with error:
// Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'IndexSet'
printIndexSet(Array<Int>([1,2]))
let indices: [Int] = [1, 2]
printIndexSet(indices)
```

what's happening here?

Comment: The literal is type IndexSet, it uses constructor `init(arrayLiteral:)`.  The Array<Int> is type Array<Int>.

Comment: @meggar No, that's not true. It works because `IndexSet` conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` and the array literal can be converted to an `IndexSet`.

Comment: @rmaddy, the conformance is achieved by implementing `init(arrayLiteral:)`

Comment: @meggar Yes but your first comment is very misleading. The literal is an array literal, not an `IndexSet`. The array literal can be converted to an `IndexSet` through its conformance to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.

Comment: @rmaddy I see your point, I thought the question was just, "why does one work and not the other", which would be because they're not both of type IndexSet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an important difference between types and literals in Swift.

As you said, [1, 2] is an array *literal*. Not an array. An array literal is basically something that can be used to create any type that conforms to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral.

You can use an array literal to create an array, but you can use it to create other types, like IndexSets.

With `printIndexSet([1, 2])` you use your array literal to create an IndexSet.

And `printIndexSet(Array<Int>([1,2]))` gives you an error because your func is expecting an IndexSet as an argument not an Array.
Hope this helps!

Update:

As @rmaddy correctly pointed out in the comments below my answer, IndexSet conforms SetAlgebra, which conforms to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral. This is why you can use your array literal to create the IndexSet.

Comment: The piece you are missing is that `IndexSet` conforms to `SetAlgebra` which in turn conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` which is why the OP's first example works.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! I've updated my answer to include this!